# automatic enumerate numbering from a specified item number

Tags: enumerate

Is there a way that I can start an enumerate numbering at, say 17, then have the succeeding item numbers automatically add 2 to the preceding one? Say, I want to typeset the answers to the odd-numbered exercises starting from 17, I want my list to show

```
17. answer 17
19. answer 19
21. answer 21
23. answer 23
.
.
.
```

I know that this can be done manually but after a while, typing the item numbers manually can become bothersome.

**Edit** I put the list in the code environment to prevent automatic renumbering.

Comment: Revolved or resolved?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC This was resolved. That is why I accepted the answer. Do you have the same problem as mine?

Comment: Yes. It worked for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom counter with [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem), and increment this counter each time it is used as the label:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{MyCounter}{17}% initial value
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic{MyCounter}\addtocounter{MyCounter}{2}}]
\item abc
\item bcd
\item xyz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```